# How to resize a PDF page with itext without scaling the content (in Java)

Tags: pdf, resize, itext

I have been trying for days to find a solution for my problem: I want to resize an existing pdf from A4 to a given individual smaller page size. And I need the real page size to be changed, not the crop box or something like that.
The original pdf will always consist of only one page and all content (e.g. texts (some with hyperlinks), images and tables) will fit into the wanted page size. In fact I want to trim the pfd page to a rectangle that exactly fits to the existing content (the content starts at the left upper corner).
As I found no way to change the page size of an existing pdf page, I tried to create a new pdf with the wanted page size and copy all the content of the original pdf to the new pdf. But that doesn't work either (I can create the new pdf page with the wanted size, but I cannot copy the content).
Any solution (iText 5 or 7) is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Go and read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for better help and a cleaner question.

Comment: *"And I need the real page size to be changed, not the crop box or something like that."* - but the crop box (or the media box which is something like that) ***is*** the real page size... if you think differently, please explain what you mean by *real page size*.

Comment: If I downsize the cropbox, then the pdf will still have all the content of the larger pagesize. That content just will be unvisible. And later someone could re-enlarge the cropbox and the unwanted contents will be visible again,am I right?

Comment: But just for a try: how could I change the cropbox in an existing document? If I open the document in stamping mode, I cannot set the cropbox and if I open it in reading mode, I can't save any changes.